# how to set paragraph column counts using MS Word

Tags: ms-word, multiple-columns

I just want to set the last para columns in below code:

`wordDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.PageSetup.TextColumns.SetCount(3);`

But it sets the page 3 columns;

So, what code can set the last para columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as a paragraph columns property - only a page columns property (TextColumns). If you want to limit the scope of TextColumns, insert a Section break before (and after, if applicable), the paragraph concerned. For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim wordDoc As Document
Set wordDoc = ActiveDocument
With wordDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range
  .InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakContinuous
  .PageSetup.TextColumns.SetCount (3)
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for answering.I'm new to the MS Word,can you give me a code for using Section break?

Comment: @yehen - That's a trivial undertaking - see my updated answer.